# Why am I getting an infinite for loop?

Tags: python, loops

For this python problem I am taking in one argument an int, this is the max length of a list I am going to be appending to. Starting with an int value of 1, I want to iterate through the list appending two more linear values until the max length is reached.

I am getting an infinite loop or something similar; I am not receiving any values but python is still processing.

This is the code where the infinite loop is occurring, wondering why? 
Code:

```
   def dbl_linear(n):
        lst_u =[1]
        while len(lst_u)<=n:
            for i in lst_u:
                lst_u.append(2*i+1)
                lst_u.append(3*i+1)
        return sorted(lst_u)

dbl_linear(10)
```

I looked up this example user had set a variable to another variable that contained a list before the for loop and then changed it back after the loop. Wondering why this is done and why it is useful?
other code:
d

```
ef dbl_linear(n):
    lst_u =[1]
    while len(lst_u)<=n:
        new_u = lst_u
        for i in lst_u:
            new_u.append(2*i+1)
            new_u.append(3*i+1)
        new_u=lst_u
    return sorted(lst_u)

dbl_linear(10)
```

Comment: I guess `for i in lst_u:` never ends because you are appending to the list in the loop itself. There are always more element to iterate over.

Comment: The `new_u = lst_u` is useless. That just creates another reference, not a copy.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding to the list as you loop over it. A list iterator simply increments a position counter and returns the value at that index until the index doesn't exist. It doesn't keep track of the length of the list up-front. In your case, by adding more elements to the end, the iterator never reaches an index that doesn't exist.

You have several options:

- Create a copy of the list first to iterate over; that copy won't grow:

  ```
  def dbl_linear(n):
      lst_u = [1]
      while len(lst_u)<=n:
          for i in lst_u[:]:  # [:] returns a shallow copy
              lst_u.append(2*i+1)
              lst_u.append(3*i+1)
      return sorted(lst_u)
  ```
- Append to a *separate, new* list and extend the original after the loop:

  ```
  def dbl_linear(n):
      lst_u = [1]
      while len(lst_u)<=n:
          new_values = []
          for i in lst_u:
              new_values.append(2*i+1)
              new_values.append(3*i+1)
          lst_u.extend(new_values)
      return sorted(lst_u)
  ```
- Use a `range()` to produce indices; this is based on taking the length *once*:

  ```
  def dbl_linear(n):
      lst_u = [1]
      while len(lst_u)<=n:
          for idx in range(len(lst_u)):
              i = lst_u[idx]
              lst_u.append(2*i+1)
              lst_u.append(3*i+1)
      return sorted(lst_u)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, so I am trying to apply those linear functions to each new element added to the list. This is what I have come up with so far but it ends up in an infinite loop as well.

Comment: 'code'def dbl_linear(n):
 
 lst_u = sorted([1])
 while len(lst_u)<n:
  new_values = []
     for i in range(n):
         new_values.append(2*lst_u[i]+1)
         new_values.append(3*lst_u[i]+1)
 lst_u.extend(new_values)
 print lst_u
dbl_linear(10)

Comment: @eeskonivich: I'm not sure why you are sorting a one-element statically-defined list there. I also can't tell if your indentation is correct. The versions *in my answer* work without looping into infinity, but the 3rd example did have a name error, that is now corrected.