# Correct way to extend list while looping?

Tags: python

To illustrate the basic idea:

```
processing_list = [0]
for item in processing_list:
  if item < 10:
    processing_list.append(item + 1)
```

For background, I am doing this because I am traversing breadth-first through a DAG, and I have certain start nodes initially, and I add their children nodes to the `processing_list` if they have not been visited before, so them and their children get subsequently processed.

The behavior adheres to my expectations, but I wanted to ask if this is correct Python or undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, provided `processing_list` and `my_list` are different lists.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. They are the same list.

Comment: Extending a list with an active iterator to it may lead to an infinite loop, see [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686813/python-append-element-with-for-in-leads-to-infinite-loop-but-not-with-for) and [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39858118/why-am-i-getting-an-infinite-for-loop).  In languages that track mutable/immutable usage of variables, this leads to a compilation error rather than whatever Python is doing.

Comment: I understand it may have consequences @metatoaster , but I am being quite careful. I'm just asking if there is any undefined behavior involved.

Comment: I don't know much about iterators, but if it simply extracts the next element from the list with every iteration, and that is the correct behavior, that should be fine.

Comment: If somehow the logic was changed to `item > 10` or `item - 1` an infinite loop will ensure.  This approach is poor form because it does not encompass a universally applicable way of doing this.

Comment: What would be a more universally applicable way @metatoaster ?

Comment: It depends on your exact use case, usage of a generator to `yield` new values, list comprehension or creating new range objects (seems like this is what you are effectively doing here anyway) are all possible, but never manipulate the list being iterated over with a for loop, i.e. not append/remove items. (As an aside, I am not one of the voters)

Comment: I see @metatoaster . My use case is the one I mentioned in my post. I have a list I am processing, and adding more things to it to process as I do it.

Comment: The more usual way to do that would be with a stack (list.pop + list.append) for dfs, or with a queue (deque.popleft + deque.append) for bfs

Comment: I couldn't find a source that guarantees the implementation of `list_iterator`.

Comment: I spoke to my professor about this @KarlKnechtel . Apparently this is a problem to this day.

Answer (score -1):

I see the example you give is just a simplified one, but given the logic in traversing your graph and identifiying valid children may be more complex, it's safer to do this without modifiying the list you are iterating over. Instead you can use a queue, and a set to track already visited nodes.

A sound way to do a breadth-first traversal would be as follows:

```
from collections import deque
start = ... # your starting node in the graph, whatever datastructure this is
target = ...

queue = deque([start])
visited = set()
results = []

while queue:
    node = queue.popleft()

    # if you have a stopping point you want to break out at
    if node == target:
        do_something()
        break

    # if we've already been here, skip to the next node
    if node in visited:
        continue

    # add this node to the visited list
    visited.add(node)

    result = process_node(node) # do whatever logic you want to here
    results.append(result)

    # get the next children and put them in the queue
    children = get_children(node)
    queue.extend(children)
```

This has a few advantages, for example once your familiar with this you can easily switch to other searching algorithms, mainly just by changing the format of the queue. Theres a great explanation of a few of these on the [redblobgames blog](https://www.redblobgames.com/pathfinding/a-star/introduction.html)